# Media queries between two resolutions

Tags: css, media-queries, responsive

I was searching how to make that a hidden section shows up to user if the resolution of his/her screen is like this:

if width < 1024px and height < 640px

and min width 1440px and height < 900px

then show the div.

I've been struggling with min-widths, max-heights, but no luck on this.

For example:
@media screen (max-width: 1023px) and (max-height: 639px), and (min-width: 1440px) and (max-height: 899px)

But it doesn't work, as expected while I was building it.

Any ideas on how to achieve that?

Comment: What means "it doesn't work"? I think is so difficult to have min-width 1440 and max-height 899 . What happens if you split that query into 2 mediaqueries?

Comment: Have you included this to your meta tags in the head? <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

Comment: @adamk22 Yes, it has the meta tag for viewport.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude it means it's not showing the div, maybe because the first rule, I don't really know, because with that query it's not showing the div

Comment: How does the CSS look like within the media query?

Comment: it's just a div to show with a display: block; from hidden;
the only way I found is what @PhyCoMah said

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**I'm using the following:**

```
/* ----------- 0 - 450px ----------- */
@media screen 
  and (max-width: 450px){
}

/* ----------- 450 - 650px ----------- */
@media screen 
  and (min-width: 451px) 
  and (max-width: 650px){
}

/* ----------- 650px - 950px ----------- */
@media screen 
  and (min-width: 651px)
  and (max-width: 950px){
}

/* ----------- 950px - 1200px ----------- */
@media screen 
  and (min-width: 951px) 
  and (max-width: 1200px){
}

/* ----------- 1200px + ----------- */
@media screen 
  and (min-width: 1201px){
}
```

Works as good as gold if you use this in your HTML:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Adjust for height and you should be set.

Comment: I was thinking on making it like that, but, if the content of the div to show will be always the same, you are repeating CSS code. But looks like it can't be another way to achieve it. Thanks!